# Youtube not buffering videos and not using any bandwidth in Chrome

Tags: networking, google-chrome, video, bandwidth, youtube

Youtube for some reason seems to be completely unwilling to load a handful of videos. It's not buffering at all, and it seems to not even be using any bandwidth (i'm monitoring it).

The issue seems to be completely hit or miss, since in some other videos in any resolution, it loads just fine.

No other devices in the network doing anything network intensive, and it's a wired connection so the usual are all taken care of. It's just that YT (or Chrome, i dont know who's the culprit here) seems to not even ask to download anything as my down traffic is about 0.2Kbs and the video is still stuck. (My connection is about 10Mb)

Answer (score 2):

Your ISP could be using a caching server. Try to change your DNS server to Google's DNS server. This will prevent the packet route being ISP manipulated. Certain ISPs uses a Caching Server to lower bandwidth costs however the servers cannot cope causing the issue you described above (I have had the exact same problems).

You can follow the instruction in [this page](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using?hl=en) from Google.

Quoted:

> **Windows**
>
> DNS settings are specified in the TCP/IP Properties window for the selected network connection.
>
> Example: Changing DNS server settings on Windows 7
>
> 1. Go to the Control Panel.
> 2. Click Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center > Change adapter settings.
> 3. Select the connection for which you want to configure Google Public DNS. For example:
>
>    - To change the settings for an Ethernet connection, right-click Local Area Connection > Properties.
>    - To change the settings for a wireless connection, right-click Wireless Network Connection > Properties.
>
>      If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
> 4. Select the Networking tab. Under This connection uses the following items, 
>      select Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) or Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6) and then click Properties.
> 5. Click Advanced and select the DNS tab. If there are any DNS server IP addresses listed there, write them down for future reference, and remove them from this window.
> 6. Click OK.
> 7. Select Use the following DNS server addresses. If there are any IP addresses listed in the Preferred DNS server or Alternate DNS server, write them down for future reference.
> 8. Replace those addresses with the IP addresses of the Google DNS servers:
>
>    - For IPv4: 8.8.8.8 and/or 8.8.4.4.
>    - For IPv6: 2001:4860:4860::8888 and/or 2001:4860:4860::8844.
> 9. Restart the connection you selected in step 3.
> 10. Test that your setup is working correctly; see Test your new settings below.
> 11. Repeat the procedure for additional network connections you want to change.

Mac and Linux instructions are available in the [link provided above](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using?hl=en).

This is ISP dependant.

There is evidence of Virgin Media's tactics by searching `Virgin Media Youtube Caching` (I am on a work network so cannot link to forums unfortunately)

Comment: I have edited it accordingly - Feel free to advise if this is the wrong format. I am fairly new here and would appreciate any constructive criticism.

Comment: Well done on the edits! If no-one has yet, welcome to Super User- stick around and make some more good answers :)

Comment: I'm already on a different dns, so that's not it probably, good thought though.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue as well. Trying to watch 4k video is almost impossible, because my system won't use more than 15mbps on YouTube (but I can easily run a speedtest at the same time and get 90mbps, confirming my 100mbps internet connection isn't the problem). Opening other videos simultaneously in new tabs/browsers/private browsing does not touch bandwidth usage. Opening another 4k video on a different device doesn't affect my throughput, so that eliminates a bit of throttling. Other devices are, however, seemingly subject to the same issue. What's left is:

1. YouTube is limiting the amount of information it sends to each PC. This is unlikely since it's very hard to enforce, let alone detect, what device behind a NAT the stream is going to, but it's Google so this is very certainly possible.
2. The ISP is limiting the streaming rate for each client. This is even more unlikely, since YouTube traffic is encrypted and the only readable information is the WAN-IP Address, which will be the same for all devices inside the network, and the port number, which will be unique for multiple sessions.
3. My router (personally owned) is capping my throughput. Possible, but this issue happens on other networks too.
4. Windows QOS. Disabling this did nothing for me, but it seems to have helped other people.

Answer (score -1):

old topic old world wide problem.

Been looking into this for years now and never found a solution to this.

What i did find out that some vids are just to hard encoded that it causes stutter, because youtube servers/backbone cant keep up and starts dropping a huge amount of frames and then it needs to skip to where it should be, it's showing you a freeze/loading icon by the time it has caught up to the actual time frame it all ready runs behind and the process starts again 1 or 2 second later.

Many other vids on 4k don't seem to have the problem,only a few have issues that also includes 8k vids they have frame drops all over the place.

When downloading the same vids and play locally 4k and 8k, there are zero issues, even when played on local mediaserver in router with chrome, default internet explorer, firefox or edge no problem when playback same vid on youtube problem comes back.

1. Conclusion it's not my pc/browser/hardware settings and not my internal network/router that has a problem.

Tried with others cousing lives 3 miles away from me different isp slower speed 100Mbit fiber vs mine 1000Mbit fiber, did the same tests with 4k and 8k vids, to rule out my connection, gave him access to my media server, playback on 4 different browsers no problem, playback on youtube with the same vid same problem.

did the test with other friend different isp slower connection 50 mbit dsl,remotely to my server 4 browsers no problem what so ever even the 8k played like charm for him, on youtube same vid same problems.

2. Conslusion it's not between isp's or speed diference that's causing this problem.

So to be direct all we did was looking at the wrong place, we checked locally on our machine and tried all so called working fixes that fixed nothing at all, the problem is at youtube servers/backbone, or a connection hub somewhere in between your isp and youtube that messes things up big time.

It's not your settings that needs fixing youtube needs to step up and fix this once and for all, this should have been fixed 5 years ago, some one is slacking of at youtube!

I ruled out locally, remotely and with different isp's with different speeds and different vids on 4k and 8k res no problem on the playback try it on youtube and we are back from where we started.

So stop looking for a problem that you can't fix, youtube needs to do the fixing!